# Main activity does not properly reference outside java class

Tags: java, android-studio, static-methods

I recently ran into a problem that seems so general and probably mundane, that mere google search does give answers to all kind of related questions, but not the exact issue itself.

I have a very simple setup where my only and thus main-activity tries to reference another java class I created so to run two simple read-from-file, write-to-file functions.

**My main activity**:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class DatenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daten);
        if(!FileTools.readString(this, HELLO_FILENAME, PROPERTY_DIRECTORY).equals("")) {
            TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_ausgabe);
            output.setText(FileTools.readString(this, HELLO_FILENAME, PROPERTY_DIRECTORY));
        }
    }

    private final static String HELLO_FILENAME = "helloString.txt";
    private final static String PROPERTY_DIRECTORY = "properties";

    public void onButtonSpeichernClick(View view){
        TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_ausgabe);
        TextView input = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edittext_eingabe);
        output.setText(input.getText());
        FileTools.saveString(this, HELLO_FILENAME, PROPERTY_DIRECTORY, output.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

And here is a cut example of the **referenced class**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class FileTools {

    private FileTools() {}

    public static String readString(Context context, String fileName){
        String result = "";
        try {
            FileInputStream in = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String zeile;
            while((zeile = reader.readLine()) != null)
                result += zeile;
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex){
            Log.e(context.getClass().getSimpleName(), ex.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
-""- etc. for one more methods, and then a variant for each of them with alternative file directory name.
}
```

Now, the issue is that Android Studio shows me the "FileTools" reference in red letters, telling me it *"cannot resolve symbol 'FileTools'"*, thus rendering all the methods within the class inaccessible to me.
 It isn't a problem with the methods themselves, because they worked before I ported them to their own class, and are now clearly public and static as well. Plus, even with a public constructor for the `FileTools.class`, Android Studio still can't find it, so the issue clearly arises further ahead.

I already tried the common custom 4 things you usually do about this kind of thing: Cleaning, Rebuilding, Sync with `Gradle` and `Invalidate Cache+Restart` all didn't work. Through an unrelated issue with a crash during updates, I even had to reinstall `Android Studio` and `Sdk` completely, but it is all the same still.

Maybe this is some really easy thing I am overlooking? I can't see it..

Btw., when trying to import FileTools (...not that that should be necessary, but desperation..), the tooltipp over that instead says *"class 'FileTools' is in the default package"*, so it **does** recognize its existence somewhere at least.

//Edit:
The requested manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.and05.lektion1.daten">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".DatenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Android Studio problems often require the `manifest` (and some times the `gradle` file too) to be shown. Would you mind sharing it? Also, some times, the problem is in the lack of `import your.package.R`.

Comment: I can not see import statement for FileTools in your activity. And I also can not see package in both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add your class **FileTools** to a package. Just add it to a package as follow, then import that package in "**main activity**":

```
package mypackageFileTools;

imports....

public class FileTools {...}
```

Java doc source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/packages.html

> It is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It was indeed that the package declaration in FileTools had been cut. (I knew it must have been something small..) However, manually inserting the right one and rebuilding and resyncing didn't work, so I had to delete and create the class anew. Now it works, even though it just has the same package "android.and05.lektion1.daten" as before.

Answer (score 0):

First: Specify correct package in each file corresponding to it's location.

Second: Add import statement for FileTools inside activity class.